# Align layout item to the right and RTL on Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to put three items in horizontal align using this code

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/address"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/lbl_address"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/txtAddress" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is gravity never worked, the ImageView always starts from the left and other items follows in the same order.

I have tried to reverse item orders in the code which will work on none RTL languages, but my application targets both, so it shows wrong on RTL supported devices.

Also I have tried RelativeLayout but items come over each other.

**Note: All languages should start from right to left, this is my desired behavior**

Comment: Can you clarify your desired behavior? It sounds like you want everything on the right side of the screen, but you mention RTL languages, so I'm not entirely sure if you mean you want it to do that only for RTL languages or for all languages. And if you want it all the way on the right for LTR languages, do you want it all the way on the left for RTL languages?

Comment: All languages should start from right to left, this is my desired behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this attribute to your root `LinearLayout` tag:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

This will make your view lay out as though the user had chosen a right-to-left language, regardless of what language they've actually chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `android:layout_width="0dp"` `android:layout_weight="1"` in your code .The `TextView` will use the rest of space .So the left image will on the left .So you can remove `android:layout_weight="1"` and change the width of `TextView` .

You can change

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtAddress" />
```

to

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/txtAddress" />
```

**Note**

- If you want to change the location of the  `LinearLayout`'s item .You can use `android:gravity="right"` .
- If you want to change the location of the `LinearLayout` ,you can use `android:layout_gravity="right"` .

And you code is `android:layout_width="match_parent"` , so the `android:layout_gravity="right"` has no effect .

And you can use `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` in your `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: I did that one but still the layout starts from left

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code in **AndroidManifest.xml**
        android:supportsRtl="true"
For support languages that start from right in app.